# unable to create a flow chart in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, flow-charts

I am trying to create a flow chart diagram in latex. I have attached the flow chart diagram below. Can anyone help me?

[image: Flow chart diagram]

This is what i have tried. I am able to draw line from node to node but unable to draw node to multinode.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
%%%>

    %usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage{acro}
    %\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float,epsf,caption,subcaption}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
    \usepackage{svg} 
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{rotating}

   \usepackage{epstopdf}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}

   %\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
   \newcommand\abs[1]{\left|#1\right|}
   \newcommand\figref{Figure~\ref}
   \renewcommand{\eqref}{\ref}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
   \usepackage{array}

    \begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
     \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
     \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
     \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    %%order of the nodes
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Selecte a pixel in the vessel mask};
    \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {obtain R,G,B values of the corresponding di pixel};
    \node (d1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {d1};
    \node (d2) [decision, left of=d1,yshift=-2cm] {d2};
    \node (d3) [decision, below of=d2,xshift=4cm] {d3};
    \node (d4) [decision, below of=d2] {d4};
    \node (d5) [decision, below of=d4,xshift=2cm] {d5};
    \node (d6) [decision, below of=d4, xshift=-2cm] {d6};
    \node (d7) [decision, below of=d6,xshift=2cm] {d7};
    \node (d8) [decision, below of=d6, xshift=-2cm] {d8};
    \node (d9) [decision, below of=d8, xshift=11cm,] {d9};
    \node (stop) [startstop, below of=d9] {Stop};


    %%%%%%%%%%%% arrows
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
    \draw [arrow] (in1) --(pro1);
    %\draw [arrow] (pro1.east) |-(d1.east);
    %\draw [arrow] (d1) -| (d9)

    %\path([d1.west]edge [d2.north])
    %\draw[arrow](d2) -- (d3)
    %\draw[arrow](d2) -- (d4)



    \end{tikzpicture};

     %% equations
     Equation numbers below  are used in the above flow diagram. 
     \begin{equation}\label{eq:D1}\tag{D1}
           g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D2}\tag{D2}
            g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D3}\tag{D3}
            g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D4}\tag{D4}
           g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D5}\tag{D5}
            g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D6}\tag{D6}
             g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D7}\tag{D7}
            g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D8}\tag{D8}
          g=10
     \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}\label{eq:D9}\tag{D9}
            g=10
     \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: this "do-it-for-me" question. We are hapy to help you, however you need  to show some of your effort. Here on site are a lot of similar diagrams, also see http://www.texample.net/ for examples. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: see: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/

Comment: Hi zarko, I have posted what i have tried. I hope that now my question is not a "do-it-for-me" question.

Comment: @Hemanth, now is better, however, please transform your code snippet to  complete small document (MWE: minimal working example) beginning with `\documentclass{...}` necessary packages, your code and ending with `\end{document}`, that we can copy your code and see, where is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, This is my first post, I really have no experience of posting questions online.

Answer (score 7):

I have attached my complete answer and image obtained by the code.

[image: Image obtained from the code]

```
    \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{tikz}
    %%%<
        \usepackage{verbatim}
        \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
        \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
        \setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
    %%%>

        %usepackage{threeparttable}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{cleveref}
        \usepackage{acro}
        %\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
        \usepackage{float,epsf,caption,subcaption}
        \usepackage{psfrag}
        \usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
        \usepackage{svg} 
        \usepackage{url}
        \usepackage{rotating}

       \usepackage{epstopdf}
       \usepackage{tikz}
       \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}

       %\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
       \newcommand\abs[1]{\left|#1\right|}
       \newcommand\figref{Figure~\ref}
       \renewcommand{\eqref}{\ref}
       \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
       \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
       \usepackage{array}

        \begin{document}
        \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
         \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
         \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
        \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
        \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
         \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        %%order of the nodes
        \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
        \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Selecte a pixel in the vessel mask};
        \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {obtain R,G,B values of the corresponding di pixel};
        \node (d1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {d1};
        \node (d2) [decision, left of=d1,yshift=-2cm] {d2};
        \node (d3) [decision, below of=d2,xshift=4cm] {d3};
        \node (d4) [decision, below of=d2] {d4};
        \node (d5) [decision, below of=d4,xshift=2cm] {d5};
        \node (d6) [decision, below of=d4, xshift=-2cm] {d6};
        \node (d7) [decision, below of=d6,xshift=2cm] {d7};
        \node (d8) [decision, below of=d6, xshift=-2cm] {d8};
        \node (d9) [decision, below of=d8, xshift=11cm,] {d9};
        \node (stop) [startstop, below of=d9] {Stop};


        %%%%%%%%%%%% arrows
        \draw [arrow] (start) --(in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) --(pro1);
\draw[arrow] (pro1) --(d1);
\draw[arrow] (d1.east)-|node[above]{yes}(d9);
\draw[arrow] (d1.west)-|node[above]{no}(d2);
\draw[arrow] (d2.east)-|node[above]{yes} (d3);
\draw[arrow] (d2)-- node[left]{no}(d4);
\draw[arrow] (d4.east)-|node[above]{yes} (d5);
\draw[arrow] (d4.west)-| node[above]{no}(d6);
\draw[arrow] (d6.east)-|node[above]{yes} (d7);
\draw[arrow] (d6.west)-| node[above]{no}(d8);
\draw[arrow] (d8.west) |- node[left]{no}(d9);
\draw[arrow] (d9.south) |- node[below]{yes}(stop.north);

\draw[arrow] (d5.south) -| node[right]{no}(d9);
\draw[arrow] (d7.south) -| node[right]{no}(d9);

\draw[arrow] (d3.south) -| node[right]{no}(d9);


\draw[arrow] (d9.east) |-node[right]{no}(0,-1);


        \end{tikzpicture};

         %% equations
         Equation numbers below  are used in the above flow diagram. 
         \begin{equation}\label{eq:D1}\tag{D1}
               g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D2}\tag{D2}
                g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D3}\tag{D3}
                g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D4}\tag{D4}
               g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D5}\tag{D5}
                g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D6}\tag{D6}
                 g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D7}\tag{D7}
                g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D8}\tag{D8}
              g=10
         \end{equation}
          \begin{equation}\label{eq:D9}\tag{D9}
                g=10
         \end{equation}

        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I allowed myself to redesign your nice solution. In this I make the following changes:

- use of the recent TikZ syntax (`\tikzset` instead `\tikzstyle`)
- exploit library positioning and use its syntax (`=of ...` instead `of= ...)
- move labels `no` and `yes` to decision block
- for all lines made common style definition
- slightly rearrange lines

After this your flowchart become:

[image]

In MWE below I delete from your MWE all what is not related to flowchart (packages, document text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes.geometric,}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
     base/.style = {draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
       io/.style = {base, trapezium,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    trapezium stretches=true,  %%%% <-- added
                    fill=blue!30},
  process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {base, diamond, fill=green!30},
every path/.style = {thick,-Stealth}
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1cm and 0.8cm]
%%order of the nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1)   [io, below=of start]    {Select a pixel\\ 
                                       in the vessel mask};
\node (pro1)  [process, below=of in1] {obtain R,G,B values of \\
                                       the corresponding di pixel};
\node (d1) [decision, below=of pro1]     {d1};
\node (d2) [decision, below left =of d1] {d2};
\node (d4) [decision, below=of d2]       {d4};
\node (d3) [decision, right=of d4 -| d1] {d3};
\node (d5) [decision, below right=of d4] {d5};
\node (d6) [decision, below left =of d4] {d6};
\node (d7) [decision, below right=of d6] {d7};
\node (d8) [decision, below left =of d6] {d8};
\node (d9) [decision, below right=of d7 -| d3.east] {d9};
\node (stop) [startstop, below=of d9] {Stop};
%%%%%%%%%%%% arrows
\draw   (start) edge (in1)
        (in1)  edge (pro1)
        (pro1) edge (d1);
\draw (d1.east) node[above right] {yes} -| (d9);
\draw (d1.west) node[above left]  {no}  -| (d2);
\draw (d2.east) node[above right] {yes} -| (d3);
\draw (d2) -- node[left]{no} (d4);
\draw (d4.east) node[above right] {yes} -| (d5);
\draw (d4.west) node[above left]  {no}  -| (d6);
\draw (d6.east) node[above right] {yes} -| (d7);
\draw (d6.west) node[above left]  {no}  -| (d8);
\draw (d8.west) node[above left]  {no}  -- ++ (-1,0) |- (d9);
\draw (d9.south) -- node[right] {yes} (stop.north);
%
\draw (d3.east) node[above right] {no} -- (d3 -| d9);
\draw (d5.east) node[above right] {no} -- (d5 -| d9);
\draw (d7.east) node[above right] {no} -- (d7 -| d9);
%
\draw (d9.east) node[above right]{no} -- ++ (1,0) |- ($(start)!0.5!(in1)$);
    \end{tikzpicture};
\end{document}
```

*Note:*

- Use of `trapezium` is tricky. If the text in node with this shape is wider than declared with `minimum width`, then shape become unexpected wide. I prevent his with set the text in two lines.
- Your (and consequently also mine) MWE doesn't reproduce sketch in your question

**Edit:**
problems with size of the `trapezium` shape is avoided if you to node with this shape to options add `trapezium stretches=true`.

Comment: Thank you for the changes and guiding me in to the community. I appreciate your help.