# A question about an easy diagram

Tags: diagrams

I want to make an easy diagram that I have attached it. Can someone help me?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Stefan Braun. Yes you are absolutely right. But I am beginner in "diagram topic" and I don't know how can I do it. Sorry.

Comment: There are many similar posts here, see for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337983/unable-to-create-a-flow-chart-in-latex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,  border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\psset{arrows=->, linewidth=0.6pt, arrowinset=0.12}
\everypsbox{\scriptsize}
 \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0.4]
& [name=MainPb] \clap{\fbox{Main Problem}}\\
& [name=MathPb] \clap{\fbox{Mathematical Problem}}\\
[name = ESol] Exact Solution &  &  [name = ASol] Approximate Solution %
\ncline[nodesep=0.1pt]{MainPb}{MathPb}\naput{modelling}%
\ncline[nodesepA=1.15ex]{MathPb}{ESol}\tlput{Analytical method}%
\ncline[nodesepA=1.6ex]{MathPb}{ASol}\trput{Numerical method}%
\end{psmatrix} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to use `tikz`. For your simple diagram basic LaTeX commands will suffice, but it will not be extensible if you ask for more. So have a look at any tutorial or introduction to TikZ, like [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf).

As a starting point, here is your diagram as `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]                (main)    {main problem};
  \node[below=of main,draw]  (math)    {mathematical problem};
  \node[below left=of math]  (exact)   {exact solution};
  \node[below right=of math] (approx)  {approximate solution};
  \draw[->] (main) -- node[left]       {modeling}          (math);
  \draw[->] (math) -- node[above left] {analytical method} (exact);
  \draw[->] (math) -- node[above right]{numerical method}  (approx);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to use the commands \usepackage{tikz} and \usetikzlibrary{positioning} in Beamer, but there are some errors, is there a particular reason?

Comment: If there is an error, there is usually a particular reason, but it probably is not related to the combination beamer+tikz.  In the code above, replace the first line by `\documentclass{beamer}`, and it will work. If you put additionally `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`, you obtain a slide with your picture. If you can't find the source of your error, post a new question containing the code of your document as well as the error message.

Comment: @ gernot. Thank you, I realized the source of error. I have used already the command \usepackage[all]{xy} and I delete it now. There is no error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To whomever it may concern: Downvoting is fine for me, but ineffective as a means of communication without an additional comment: Not many can see the downvoting; I only notice because the reputation change is not a multiple of 10. Otherwise I'm quite clueless whether expressing the view that "tikz is the answer" is considered inappropriate, or whether the solution is inadequate/too trivial to post, or whether ... I just can't guess.

Comment: @gernot, for use in `beamer` you need to consider that standard frame (slide) has limited space. For this reason probably would be fine to change node distances. For example `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm and 0mm]`

Comment: @gernot, (continuation above comment): or redesign the nodes positions as:   `\node[below left=of math.south]  (exact)   {exact solution};
  \node[below right=of math.south] (approx)  {approximate solution};
  \draw[->] (main) -- node[left]       {modeling}          (math);
  \draw[->] (math) -- node[left=2mm]   {analytical method} (exact);
  \draw[->] (math) -- node[right=2mm]  {numerical method}  (approx);`

Comment: @Zarko My comment just addressed the issue raised by the OP that he had a problem when using tikz with beamer. So I demonstrated that the tikz solution also works in the beamer class, in a frame. Layouting the picture for a presentation is a different question. As it turned out, the problem was not related to tikz.

Answer (score 2):

It is a tree. Hence, I would use Forest.

First, a basic version:

```
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{}{draw},
  for tree={edge+={->}, font=\sffamily, l sep'+=30pt},
  label me/.style={
    edge label/.process={On=?_w}{n}{1}{left, anchor=mid east}{right, anchor=mid west}{node [midway, ##1, font=\sffamily] {#1}},
  },
  [Main Problem
    [Mathematical Problem, label me=Modelling
      [Exact Solution, label me=Analytical Method]
      [Approximate Solution, label me=Numerical Method]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: basic]

Nest, a fancier version:

```
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{}{draw=darkgray, blur shadow, top color=white, bottom color=gray!10},
  for tree={edge+={-Latex, darkgray}, font=\sffamily, text=darkgray, l sep'+=30pt, rounded corners},
  label me/.style={
    edge label/.process={On=?_w}{n}{1}{left, anchor=mid east}{right, anchor=mid west}{node [midway, ##1, font=\sffamily, text=gray] {#1}},
  },
  [Main Problem
    [Mathematical Problem, label me=Modelling
      [Exact Solution, label me=Analytical Method]
      [Approximate Solution, label me=Numerical Method]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: fancier]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{}{draw},
  for tree={edge+={->}, font=\sffamily, l sep'+=30pt},
  label me/.style={
    edge label/.process={On=?_w}{n}{1}{left, anchor=mid east}{right, anchor=mid west}{node [midway, ##1, font=\sffamily] {#1}},
  },
  [Main Problem
    [Mathematical Problem, label me=Modelling
      [Exact Solution, label me=Analytical Method]
      [Approximate Solution, label me=Numerical Method]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{}{draw=darkgray, blur shadow, top color=white, bottom color=gray!10},
  for tree={edge+={-Latex, darkgray}, font=\sffamily, text=darkgray, l sep'+=30pt, rounded corners},
  label me/.style={
    edge label/.process={On=?_w}{n}{1}{left, anchor=mid east}{right, anchor=mid west}{node [midway, ##1, font=\sffamily, text=gray] {#1}},
  },
  [Main Problem
    [Mathematical Problem, label me=Modelling
      [Exact Solution, label me=Analytical Method]
      [Approximate Solution, label me=Numerical Method]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```